# Restore Database without taking RDP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

I have a DB server 192.168.X.X, Now due to some Issue with the domain user we are unable to get the RDP of that server. but we can get the DB connected from other server which is there on the network.

Now I want to restore the database on 192.168.X.X, so Is it possible to restore the DB without taking the RDP of the server.

Any help will be appreciated.

I tried this step but with no luck:  [Link](http://jdav.is/2012/08/08/restore-database-from-a-network-path-in-sql-management-studio/)

I tried to Restore the DB with T-SQL code as well:

```
Use master

RESTORE DATABASE TEST
FROM DISK = '\\192.168.X.X\New folder.bak'
```

But it gives me an error.

Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot open backup device '\192.168.X.X\New folder.bak'. Operating system error 1326(The user name or password is incorrect.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: When you go to restore DB option and browse, you can go to the location where backup is residing(you need to have read/write permission on that location) and afterwards, it should be straight forward. No need of using UNC path.

Comment: Technically, the service account running the SQL Engine needs access to the backup file location.

Comment: How come the linked instructions didn't work? Was there an error message? What'd it say? Something else?

Comment: IMO, we need more details, including error messages. It isn't clearly stated that a linked server was used, perhaps an RDP connection was established to a different machine, SSMS started on that machine and from there log on to the destination SQL Server?

Comment: As everyone mentionned it, it is a pretty strait forward process (I never RDP to a SQL server to restore a DB). If you can't, we will need more information about what you are doing and the error you get. Thanks

Comment: As mentioned by @Learning_DBAdmin I did that, but the problem is when I goto that location and select that backup it says "No backup selected to be restored"

Comment: Still hard to say without more specifics. I suggest you skip the GUI for the restore and just type your RESTORE command. Now you can show use the command you executed and possibly the error message you got. It is sometimes indefinitely more difficult to understand the quirks in the GUI compared to the end result: the RESTORE command(s).

Comment: I tried the TSQL query as well. I posted above

Comment: It seems that the service account for the SQL Server service don't have privileges to the share/file that you point to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access and sufficient rights to the database on the SQL server via SSMS.

Create a shared folder on a different network server 192.I.Have.Access.  Grant the SQL engine and agent accounts read and write access to the shared folder.

You can take backups to the share (with write access) and you can restore backups from the share (with read access).  Direct access to folders on the server the SQL instance is installed on is not required.

**BE-AWARE** If someone besides you is responsible for SQL backups on the server.  Taking backups and/or restoring database can and probably will break the backup chain.  This will make disaster recovery for some period impossible, understand the implications to disaster recovery in your organization before making a one off backup or doing a restore.

---

If the only copy of the backup you want to restore is on the server in a folder you can not access; Congratulations you just learned why it is important copy backups to a safe location on a different server for disaster recovery.  I hope the lesson has not been overly expensive.